# averaging circuit when number of inputs is dynamic

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have sensors that measure the weight of each person in a room and also a sensor to count the number of people(this is an example, my application is similar but not this). I need to find the average weight. 
I can use an opamp averager circuit. But the number of people are variable, therefore, I need to change Rf and input branches/resistors (to V-) every time there is a change in number of people. Is there a workaround? Please help !

Answer (score -1):

It's old technology now but the [AD633](http://www.analog.com/-/media/analog/en/products/image/functional-block-diagrams/ad633-fbl.png?w=900) multiplier is capable of division.

[image]

*Figure 1. AD633 block diagram.*

For division you put the multiplier in the feedback loop as shown in Figure 16 of the datasheet.

[image]

Read and understand the datasheet and device constraints carefully before you jump in.

I think if you search this site for the AD633 you will find recommendations for more recent devices that have better performance.

Comment: Unless I am misreading the question this does not really answer it. OPs issue is how to count the number of inputs and divide by that number dynamically using simple "analog" circuitry.

Comment: I read it that he has an analog reading of the weight and an analog value of the number of people. If it's a digital number of people he'll have to convert it to analog for the division (or do the whole job digitally which would probably be more sensible).

Comment: Thanks for your response and help!! However, my problem is basically the variable input. the inputs can be weight of 2 people one day and 6 people the next. Without changing the hardware circuitry, how do i find the average?

Comment: But you didn't clarify who's understanding is correct - Trevor's or mine? "*Without changing the hardware circuitry ...*": you didn't share with us what the circuitry is. Are you able to count the number of people already or is that the problem? Is the count a digital or analog signal? Why are you not using a micro? Edit your question to improve it and include all the details. This site is very active and the fact that you didn't get multiple responses is a sign that the question is unclear.